# Create multiple bitmap objects fast

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

What's the fastest way to create 500+ Bitmaps from 500+ different image files? They need to be HQ resized and converted to the pixel format Format32bppPArgb for faster painting.

I'm creating each Bitmap as follows:

```
Bitmap resized;
using (Bitmap original = new Bitmap(pathToFile))
{
  resized = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
  resized.SetResolution(original.HorizontalResolution, original.VerticalResolution);
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resized))
  {
    g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    g.DrawImage(original, 0, 0, width, height);
  }
}
```

I'm running a new BackgroundWorker to handle each Bitmap creation, which speeds up the process substantially, but I'm still looking for more speed (without sacrificing image quality). Pre-sizing images is not a possibility for what I'm trying to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Do you need the bitmaps created in parallel?

Comment: You might want to take a look at `async` and `await`. You can create the `Bitmap` in a task.

Comment: I need them created in parallel because any of the images could potentially be accessed by a mouse click. For this project I'm using .NET Framework 4.0, so I'm not sure if async and await would be usable.

Comment: If you create a list of tasks for each image, then you can await all of them via the Task.WhenAll([yourlistoftasks]).ContinueWith(results =>{}); (code is mirky since I have lots of extension methods on the task library). But point being is this executes everything asynchronously without blocking the thread and returns back when everything finishes. Kind of cool.

Comment: If you are already using `BackgroundWorker`, and you start at least as many `BackgroundWorker` instances concurrently as you have CPU cores, then you're already going as fast as you can. You may find the code is more maintainable and easier to read and write if you use some other threading mechanism; `BackgroundWorker` features don't appear to be used here. But it won't go _faster_ with some other mechanism.

Comment: Also, I see that your original `Bitmap` object is being read from a file. That most likely means that the _file_ is the bottleneck here; the disk is only going to be able to service so many read operations per second, which you may exceed with just one or a few threads running.

Comment: Peter, that's a great point about the file probably being the bottleneck. Thanks for the tips everyone.